# Using SQLite for Billions of Records

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, csv

In my WPF app, I am inserting Customer Data into SQLite Database. I have 2 tables (Zip and Customer). The Data can grow up to billions. I need fast insertions and retrieval from the DB.

I am using SQLite as the application will be used on a single system only. According to my research SQLite can handle TBs of Data so I want to know if there is something wrong with it?

Previously I used MySQL and EF but Insertion and Retrievals were very slow.

These are the two tables. While fetching Customer info from ZipCode will be added to record.

```
CREATE TABLE ZIPCODE(
                    Zip NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY ,
                    City VARCHAR,
                    County VARCHAR,
                    State VARCHAR
                );
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
                Phone NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY,
                FirstName VARCHAR,
                LastName VARCHAR,
                Address VARCHAR,
                Zip NUMERIC,
                Status CHAR(5),
                Category CHAR(10),
                Options CHAR(5),
                Email VARCHAR,
                Seconds NUMERIC,
                FOREIGN KEY(Zip) REFERENCES ZIPCODE(Zip)
            );
```

Below is C# function i am using to insert Data.

```
public int AddCustomersToDB(List<Customer> customers)
        {
            int invalidCount = 0;
            try
            {
                _dbConnection.Open();
                using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(_dbConnection))
                {
                    using (var transaction = _dbConnection.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        foreach (Customer c in customers)
                        {
                            string values = String.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\",\"{5}\",\"{6}\",\"{7}\",\"{8}\",\"{9}\"", c.Phone, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Address, c.Zip, c.Status, c.Category, c.Options, c.Email, c.Seconds);
                            cmd.CommandText = String.Format(@"INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(Phone,FirstName,LastName,Address,Zip,Status,Campaign,Options,Email,Seconds) VALUES ({0});", values);
                            try
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (SQLiteException e)
                            {
                                invalidCount++;
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
                return invalidCount;
            }
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                throw new Exception("SQLiteException:" + e.Message);
            }
            finally { _dbConnection.Close(); }
        }
```

It need some suggestions regarding this approach, I have Code on GitHub so if anyone want to look at full code i can share that too.

Comment: Use SQL command parameters. Your code is susceptible to SQL injections and will easily break when any of your values contains a quote. Also with command parameters you don’t need to care about properly converting date/times, numbers, bools and so on to strings.

Comment: Like this for Example ?
```INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(Phone,FirstName,LastName,Address) VALUES (?,?,?,?)``` and then using ``` cmd.Parameters.Add(param,"abc") ```

Comment: Close, but you would usually name your parameters, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thank you , any idea about SQLite ?

Comment: Unless you're actually using floating point numbers as a primary key (bad idea), use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, not `NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY`. Your database will be smaller and it'll be faster to fetch data based on looking up the PK. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: I don't have fetch data based on primary key, i have added primary key to avoid data duplication. Zip,City,County and type would be used to filter data. Any idea about how to make it fast ?

Comment: Also Will it be right if I use ```Phone CHAR(10) , Zip CHAR(5)``` as Phone will always be 10 chars and Zip will be 5 chars long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change a few things. I'd use sql command parameters as it will prevent sql injection attacks and clean up your code. The try/catch/finally block makes your code more error prone as you have to manually dispose of the connection. Wrapping your code in a [using block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) will ensure that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs within the using block.

Regarding your SQLite questions - the [maximum database size for a SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) database is approximately 140 terabytes. So it can handle a lot of data, **but do you want to use a SQLite database of that size**?

I've used SQLite on several projects, but never for large datasets. The downside of using it for large datasets is that it stores the entire database in a single disk file and many file systems limit the maximum size of files to something less than SQLite's limits.

I would review the following for general usage guidelines: [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Sample piece of code showing paramater use and using block:

```
        var customers = new List<Customer>(); // get your customers

        using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("your connection string"))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();

            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Phone, FirstName) VALUES(@param1, @param2)";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    foreach (var c in customers)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", c.Phone);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", c.FirstName);

                        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank You, I am working to use command parameters. I have few questions.

1- I have a connection variable in Singelton class which I am using for all queries. I open this connection every time i query and close it afterwards. Is this approach fine or i should create new connection on every query instead of opening and closing same connection?
2- I have studied the link you provide, as file size limit is around 16TB and my data would be in GBs so would it be wrong to use SQLite? If i use other DB (MySQL e.g) I must install it on client's machine, wouldn't it overload clients system?

Comment: 1) Using a Singleton for a connection object is a really bad idea. There is no reason to do this whatsoever. You want to open the connection as late as possible (right before executing any SQL) and closing it as soon as possible (right after the last bit of data has been extracted). 2) You should be fine with SQLite. An RDBMS like MySQL or SQL Server are installed on servers.

Comment: Basically I have an SQLiteDbHandler Class which i thought should be singleton, Can you look at the code on Github `ExcelReplacment/Helper/DbHandler` ? 
 https://github.com/faizankhan1995/ExcelReplacment

Comment: I see what you are doing. Class is singleton, but you are opening/closing connections based on my suggestion. I misunderstood you. Another suggestion, I would change your code to use the async versions like OpenAsync and ExecuteNonQueryAsync.

Comment: What difference would it make ? Now adding data to db is much faster now because of Query parameters ? Or using statements might have an effect ?

Comment: Its possible that SQLite is caching the parameterized query plans and reusing them on repeated execution. SQL Server does this. Async DB commands  are critical in achieving scale, throughput, and latency for I/O bound operations.

Comment: One last thing. Can you review the CustomerFilter.cs file https://github.com/faizankhan1995/ExcelReplacment/blob/master/ExcelReplacment/Model/CustomersFilter.cs
I am using this class to create Query based on Filters but i think i'm not doing it right because i am using string concatenation to create the queries based on filters. Can you suggest some better way of doing it.

Comment: You are using Java naming conventions for some of your methods - which I would change to follow c# naming conventions. I would use string interpolation in GetCorrespondingQuery.

Comment: `string zips = "\"" + string.Join("\",\"", _zips) + "\"";` so after creating zips i should use it like "{zip}" instead of concatenation ?

Comment: String interpolation provides a more readable and convenient syntax to create formatted strings. You would apply it to your variables in GetCorrespondingQuery. It's not required will just make things more readable.

Comment: Another thing, before writing data to csv file i read whole data in a List, do you think its fine ? Other way would be to return SqliteDataReader but that would increase the coupling, your comments ?

Comment: List is fine. Keep SqliteDataReader in the data layer.

Comment: In that case number of records that can be retrieved will be limited by Ram, what could be the better approach to avoid out of memory issue ?

Comment: You can look into applying row_number and limit to your queries.